# How can you z-index text / div behind a scrolling fixed nav header?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the div behind the scrolling header like it is for the footer.

The footer is

```
#rt-footer-surround {
     color: #686868;
     background-color: #2E244E;
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 900;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 10px;
     position: fixed;
}
```

but I cannot replicate it for the header.

the site in question is here:

[site with z-index issue](http://curtisj.trafficflo.net/)

Comment: [You mean like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5HuL/)?

Comment: Actually no it is not like that.  If you add a background image that is fixed behind the text and the header then it would be what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I came up with to solve the problem.  Jquery.

Essentially my question was asking for this in the first place.

If you have content in a div you can place a nav bar in that div as a position:relative i.e. relative to that div.

What you cannot do via css is have the content in that div scroll up and stay underneath the nav bar you created.  Furthermore when the nav menu area scrolls beyond the top of the screen it will then disappear.

So the jquery code I used does two things.  It allows you to take a nav menu bar i.e. width 600px / height 50px and place it in its relative position anywhere you like. Furthermore, when it reachs the top of a users screen it will stop/halt and allow that to be the menu that is visible while everything else scrolls underneath that menu area.

Now, I don't think this is anything really new from Jquery but what is ultra convenient is that you can define a menu nav bar in any div position you want.  Have a regular menu at the top and another menu perhaps below a slider or some content further down the page.

I will share the code if that is ok with SO... I paid for it myself.

Oh and here are two websites I have employed it on.

http://isaerudition.com/study-pages & 
[This is for a client I am preparing his website...](http://curtisj.trafficflo.net/)

```
// JavaScript Document
/*     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed'),
            elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
            elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
            //alert(elTop); 
            jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
                var height = jQuery(window).height();
                var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                if(scrollTop>=elTop){
                    //add fixed
                    jQuery(el).addClass('scroll_fixed').css("left",elLeft+"px");
                }else{
                    //clear fixed
                    jQuery(el).removeClass('scroll_fixed').attr('style','');
                }
            })
        }
    })
       */
       // JavaScript Document
    /* jQuery(window).load(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed'),
            elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
            elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
            //alert(elTop); 
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft);
        }
    }) */
    var setInter = null;
    var session = null;

    setInter = setInterval(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed');
            session =  jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll');
            //alert(session);

            if(session == '2'){
                jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','2');
            }else{
                jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','1');
            }
            if(session == '1'){
                setValue(el);
            }
        }
    }, 200);
    function setValue(el){
        var setScroll = jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll');
        elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
        elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
        //alert(elTop);
        jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','2');
        scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft);
    };
    function scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft){
        jQuery(document).unbind('scroll').scroll(function(){
            //alert(elTop);
            var height = jQuery(window).height();
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop>=elTop){
                //add fixed
                jQuery(el).addClass('scroll_fixed').css("left",elLeft+"px");
            }else{
                //clear fixed
                jQuery(el).removeClass('scroll_fixed').attr('style','');
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the z-index style, you must also use either `position:fixed;`, `position:absolute;`, ,or `position:relative;` on the same object you wish to style.

Then, you can simply use a div to represent your header, footer, and main content section as follows:

```
<div class="head"></div>
<div class="mainbody"></div>
<div class="foot"></div>
```

Or alternatively, you can use the `<head>`,`<main>` and `<footer>` tags instead of divs. As far as coding and visuals are concerned, there is no difference.

Also, you don't have to put a massive number on the z-index. As long as one element's z-index is greater than another one's, that element will always be layered above, whether it is 900 over 1, or 2 over 1.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your help.  This is harder/more difficult because I am using a template that already exists and thus trying to follow their framework with chrome dev tools.  Let me see if i follow you correctly, the head and foot div should be z-index of let's say 2.  then the main body should be 0 or 1?  I am thinking this but I cannot get it to work.  the footer is fine but the head isn't working... maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Well you have the z-index values correct, but did you make sure to put one of the position styles on all your elements? z-index doesn't work if you haven't defined one, since it reverts to the default position:static, which doesn't work with z-index.

Comment: I have a solution... lol and it was Jquery.  lol... I had to do it.  it's pretty cool though.  Worked out well.  I can post the solution and the code if SO allows me. basically it takes a relative div position and makes it fixed.  and you can define where you want it fixed compared to any div you have.  I paid good money for it ;)